# Rails nested model forms: validate presence of foreign key unless user creates new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In have a pretty simple rails app, here's my code:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :category_id, :category_attributes    
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

#app/views/posts/_form.html.haml
= simple_form_for(@post) do |f|
  = f.association :category
  = f.simple_fields_for :category do |cat_f|
    = cat_f.input :name
```

So when creating a new post, I have the option to choose a category (from the select menu) or create a new one (if it doesn't exist).

I want to validate that **category_id** is present, unless the user opts to create a new category

I'm guessing there's some kind of rails way to solve this problem - I know that I can't just add `validates :category_id, :presence => true` as this will cause form submission to fail when the user decides to create a new category (and doesn't select one from the drop-down).

**Second Question:**
I recently read a useful rails tutorial that showed you how to toggle between displaying the category select menu and the new category fields so that only one of the two is present on screen at any given time. Anyone got a link to something like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I have fixed this by replacing:

```
validates :category_id, :presence => true
```

with

```
validates :category, :presence => true
```

It seems to work. 
Strange one.

PS

I can only imagine that this works because `:category` is considered present if the user selects something from the drop-down list **OR** if they create a new category using the nested form, whereas previously, with my original code, :category_id was only considered present when the user selected something from the drop-down and **NOT** when they created a new record.

Comment: Kudos for actually following up your original post, it really helped me out today.

Comment: Excellent! It, combined with proper unit testing, helped me in a larger confusing situation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your PostsController, you probably want to check the incoming parameters in your create action to see if category_id is your default value (here, -1), and if so, create a new category from the text field. Something like this:

```
def create
  if params[:post][:category_id] != -1
    category = Category.create params[:post][:category_name]
    # make sure category is attached to post
  end

  # rest of your create action
end
```

And something similar in your update action.

As for your second question, that's probably less Rails and better handled by Javascript. You could pretty easily have a radio button for 'use existing category' or 'create new category', and then use javascript to swap the DOM objects appropriately.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, but I think I've fixed this. See my own answer for details